# 3 equal height views using autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am a beginner in autolayout. I have all my views created programmatically.

What I want is 3 equal height vertical splits using autolayout programmatically?

My expectation is in portrait or landscape the height of all 3 views will adjust and width will remain same (screenwidth)

Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: Before ask example you must have upload a snapcode that you try . and ya what ever you need output just upload one UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a UIStackView?

```
lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView: UIStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.firstView, self.secondView, self.thirdView])
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    stackView.spacing = 10.0
    return stackView
}()
```

Then use autolayout to make the height of one of the view's height. The stackView will take care of the other two views' height

Comment: You probably might need to update the constraint when you switch orientation

Comment: But I thought thats the whole point of autolayout..I wont have to do anything when orientation changes

Comment: It depends on what the constraint is using as a value. For example if it's a constant 100 height, you wont need to. But if you use like 30% of the superview's height, then you'll have to do a little more leg work to make it render properly like taking the max value between height and width of the screen

Comment: @hooliooo You might need to add this line 
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Answer (score 0):

Use a vertical stack view by dragging "Vertical Stack View" `UIStackView` from the object library. Set up it's auto layout constraints and divide it in the number of pieces you need. You don't need to manage it from your code.

Comment: All my views have already been created and use autoresizingmask as of now. It will be hard to migrate to IB for now

Comment: You can create stack views in code as well, but it's more work.